# FFmpeg save stream to mp3

Tags: ios, audio, ffmpeg

I have an iOS project that play online radio streams, it is use FFmpeg to play. Also I added ability to record streams, decode streams via `avcodec_decode_audio4` function, and write output to `.wav` file. But this files are too big, because it is uncompressed format, so I want to decode files to `.mp3`.

I have found couple ways to convert audio but only when audio it is ready file, but I want decode to some compressed format as soon as I get chunk of data from stream, not ready file.

Is it possible?
Can you give me some advise how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ffmpeg (aka libav) to encode the audio you're reading with `avcodec_decode_audio4` into a file as mp3, as long as `libav` was configured with lame (`--enable-libmp3lame`).

Basically, you configure an mp3 codec, then call `avcodec_encode_audio2` (who names these things?) on the progressive output of `avcodec_decode_audio4`.

The [canonical example](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/output-example_8c-source.html) can be confusing because it also deals with video, but you should be able to tease the details you want out of it.

This [post on transcoding audio](https://arashafiei.wordpress.com/2012/10/22/using-avcodec_encode_audio2/) by arashafiei is broadly helpful.

Comment: These names are from historical APIs that have since then been deprecated. At some point there was an avcodec_encode_audio() function (that's "1"), and the function prototype was changed (probably uint8_t *data + int size -> AVPacket pkt), and thus avcodec_encode_audio2() was born, and avcodec_encode_audio() was (for compatibility) kept and called avcodec_encode_audio2() internally. Eventually, it was removed, and now you onnly have avcodec_encode_audio2().

Comment: the link to the post on transcoding audio by arashafiei is dead